# Gridview with controls (Some rows' buttons does not fire)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building a project using ASP.NET and c#

I use gridview to display data, and on each row i have buttons to edit and delete a row.. (gridview is populated from database)

I noticed that some rows' buttons fire events. and most rows at the bottom do not fire the button click event.

What's the common reason for this?